# Would this be a copyright issue?

Tags: copyright, children

I had an idea for a book like "[Brown Bear, Brown Bear, What Do You See?](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/759611.Brown_Bear_Brown_Bear_What_Do_You_See_)" but based on a popular children’s movie. If the artwork is my own, would there be any possible copyright issues?

Comment: What do you mean by "a book like 'Brown Bear, Brown Bear'"? In what ways would they be similar? And what do you mean by "based on a popular children's movie"? As in, using the actual characters from said movie?

Answer (score 4):

> I had an idea for a book like **Brown Bear, Brown Bear, What Do You See?** (by Eric Carle)...

**Ideas cannot be copyrighted.**

The book and its sequels use **predictable, repetitive text** which is a common in pre-reading children's books. [This link](https://imaginationsoup.net/picture-books-predictable-repetitive-text/) has other popular examples.

I assume your idea uses a variation on the structure of *one thing leading to another*, and not the exact phrase from **Brown Bear**.

> but based on a popular children’s movie

**That's a problem.**

The story, characters, and fictional locations from this movie are probably still under **copyright** (unless it was made before the early 1920s).

**Trademarks** may be established for the most recognizable elements including character designs, imitative art styles, catchphrases, especially where these elements have already been licensed for marketing tie-ins and representation in other media *including children's books*.

Furthermore, any 'popular children's movie' has well-established **intellectual property (IP)** that extends to character-likenesses and costume style – visual elements that may appear in your artwork to suggest the film.

Of course **this is not legal advice**.

From your very brief description 'based on a popular children's movie', your book could be claimed to trade on the brand and the recognition of the film. It would not be 'just' copyright that you are liable for.